# Copy SQL Server data with auto-incremented and recursive data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with SQL Server 2008 and have two tables like:

Table 1:

```
| id   | value | parentId |
+------+-------+----------+
|  1   | pra1  |     2    |
|  2   | 3tes  |     3    |
|  3   | 4tes  |     4    |
|  5   | pra2  |     1    |
|  6   | 3tes  |     3    |
|  7   | pra6  |     2    |
```

Table 2:

```
| testid | subject | value |
+--------+---------+-------+
|   1    |    5    | case1 |
|   2    |    5    | case2 |
|   3    |    7    | case3 |
```

And there are some notes for these tables:

1. `table1.id` is the primary key of table1 and auto-incremented
2. `table1.parentId` is part of `table1.id` list. They are recursive.
3. `table2.testid` is the primary key of table2 and auto-incremented
4. `table2.subject` is a foreign key of table2 and refers to `table1.id`

I would like copy the two tables data into another DB. How can I write some scripts to copy data and auto assign ids/parentIds to these tables.

Comment: The general idea is to create tables without constraints (pk, fk's, auto-increment etc). Import data. Create the constraints. (I have never done this on MS SQL Server.)

Comment: What do you mean with auto assign ids/parentids. By your question it sounds like it's a plain copy, but i guess you mean to copy the data and implement their own auto-increments in accordance to their latest values?

Comment: what is your output data format?

Answer (score 1):

If you're inserting into the new database and need to maintain the Primary key, auto increment, and Foreign key constraints on both tables, you'll need to export values. Table1 for example, on the new db you'll need to add Table1.parentValue and make sure parentID is a nullable field.

```
Insert into DB2.Table1 (value, parentvalue) 
SELECT o.value, p.value 
FROM DB1.Table1 o
LEFT JOIN DB1.Table1 p on p.parentId = o.ID
```

Your table will look like this:

```
| id   | value | parentId | parentValue|
+------+-------+----------+------------+
|  1   | pra1  |  NULL    | 3tes       |
|  2   | 3tes  |  NULL    | 4tes       |
|  3   | 4tes  |  NULL    | NULL       | <-- there is ID 4 above.
|  5   | pra2  |  NULL    | par1       |
|  6   | 3tes  |  NULL    | 4tes       |
|  7   | pra6  |  NULL    | 3tes       |
```

Then "back fill" the parentID

```
UDPATE o set o.parentID = p.ID FROM DB2.Table1 o INNER JOIN DB2.Table1 p WHERE p.parentvalue = o.value
```

Drop the column parentValue and use similar logic for Table2.

-John